# How to grant permission to SQL Server FileTable other Windows users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions, filetable

On SQL Server 2012 I've successfully configured FILESTREAMs and created a FileTable table.  I am able to access the FileTable via the UNC path (`\\server\share\tabledirectory...`).  However, I'm stumped as far as how to grant permission so that other Windows users can remotely access it.  I've tried granting select/insert/update/delete permission to the Windows user accounts to the FileTable table:

```
GRANT SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT on TableName to [DOMAIN\joeuser]
```

...but that had no effect.

Comment: Needed to leave the windows share as a Globalroot path and manage permissions through table properties, not Windows share properties

Comment: Could you clarify for me please?  And what do you mean by "table properties"?  Can you give me an example?

Comment: Please find the following link to help you http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645923.aspx#enabling

Comment: Hmmm....maybe you sent the wrong link or my question wasn't clear.  I know how to set up FILESTREAMs and how to create a FileTable.  My problem is I don't know how to control fine-grained access to the underlying FileTable network share.  In other words, how to I go about granting access to the network share for a single Windows user?

Comment: At the server level (or server instance if you have multiple instances on a machine) the users must have been added (or added a login for the group or domain they are part of depending on how you want to manage this) with status of Connection Grant and Login enabled.. and then at the database level (which hold the FILETABLE) have those permissions to access the folder by the entire path. To be able to browse at \server\instance\filestream directory name\ they need addition permission of ALTER for some reason.